# Pass a HashMap as parameter in Java

Tags: java, hashmap

I have the main class `Library` where I create:

```
HashMap<String, HashSet<String>> students_books = new HashMap<String, HashSet<String>>();
```

Then I'll have class `Student` where I'll make a constructor who will take the HashMap as a parameter like this:

```
public class Student {

    private Student(HashMap students_books){
```

then, back in my main class (Library) I create a `student` object where I want to put the HashMap as parameter:

```
Student student = new Student(*HashMap as parameter*);
```

What I'm not finding is how I can do this and how the `Student` class knows what type of HashMap I'm passing, for example, `<String, HashSet<String>>`

Comment: You can't construct `Student` at all if it's constructor is private, but the answer is to specify the `HashMap` parameter the same way you specified `students_books` in your first piece of code.

Comment: Use interface Map when declaring your HashMap variable. BTW, return type is not allowed in constructor.

Comment: why do you even add a 'void' return type to your "so called" constructor?

Comment: Fixed it and it's now working, thank you

Comment: You should pass in `Map` instead of `HashMap` and `Set` instead of `HashSet`.  In Java it is recommended to use the interfaces instead of the implementation.  So `students_books` (should be `studentBooks`) should be a `Map<String, Set<String>> `.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> knows what type of HashMap I'm passing

Firstly, your method is not a constructor since it has return type, remove its return type and public your constructor. Then just force them to pass what type of HashMap you want by doing this

```
public class Student {

    public Student(HashMap<String, HashSet<String>> students_books){
```

and then passing them like this

```
HashMap<String, HashSet<String>> students_books = new HashMap<String, HashSet<String>>(); 
Student student = new Student(students_books);
```

Comment: This is wrong. private void Student(HashMap<String, HashSet<String> students_books) is not a constructor. remove the return type

Comment: Thanks @Yohannes. just fix it

Answer (score 5):

To answer your question - "How to pass HashMap as a parameter" and how Student class know the type
I am providing a more generic and standard way of doing this

```
Map<K,V> books = new HashMap<K,V>(); // K and V are Key and Value types
Student student = new Student(books); // pass the map to the constructor

..
//Student Constructor
public Student(Map<K,V> books){
..
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your Student class constructor(which currently a method, since it has a return type), the argument is not utilizing generic type.

Please change it to the following.

```
public StudentHashMap(HashMap<String, HashSet<String>> students_books){

}
```

This will ensure type safetey during compile time

Answer (score 1):

What you did is a private method, not a constructor.
change your method to this:

```
public Student(HashMap<String, HashSet<String>> student_books) {
    //your code here
}
```

I this way it will a true constructor you wanted, hope this will help